# Creating FabricJS object inside function

Tags: javascript, oop, fabricjs

I don't understand where the problem is exactly. Most likely it's in OOP.

So I create my own class to work with canvas through FabricJS, and create method to add door (I just do cupboard). This method creates fabric.Rect.
I called this method 3 times and got 3 doors (rects), as it should be.
But when I try to select one of them canvas returns only last one.

Look at the example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vasek18/w2e17803/), try to select one of the two first doors.

```
    function Dveri_kupe(options){
    var defaultOptions = {
        doorWidth: 200,
        doorHeight: 400,
        doorDivisionWidth: 5,
        totalWidth: 735,
        totalHeight: 500,
        startOffsetTop: 50,
        startOffsetLeft: 50,
        strokeColor: "#aaa",
        fillStyle: "#ccc",
        lineWidth: "5"
    }
    for(var option in defaultOptions) this[option] = options && options[option]!==undefined ? options[option] : defaultOptions[option];

    var this_ = this;
    this.doorArr = []

    canvas = this._canvas = new fabric.Canvas(options.canvasID);
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
        if (options.target) {
            console.log('Object. ID = ' + options.target.id + " ", options.target);
        }
    });

    this.addDoor = function(options){
        var doorQuan = this.doorArr.length;

        console.log("Door add: id = dver" + doorQuan)

        this.doorArr[doorQuan] = new fabric.Rect({
            left: this.startOffsetLeft + this.doorWidth * doorQuan,
            top: this.startOffsetTop,
            fill: this.fillStyle,
            width: this.doorWidth,
            height: this.doorHeight,
            strokeWidth: this.lineWidth,
            stroke: this.strokeColor,
            id: "dver" + doorQuan
        });

        canvas.add(this.doorArr[doorQuan]);

        return doorQuan;
    }

    this.tellMeAStory = function(){
        console.log(canvas)
        console.log(this.doorArr)
    }
};

var dveri_kupe;
window.onload = function(){
    dveri_kupe = new Dveri_kupe({canvasID : "shkaf"});
    var doorQuan = 3;
    for(var i = 0; i < doorQuan; i++){
        // console.log(dveri_kupe.addDoor())
        dveri_kupe.addDoor()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small correction:

```
var defaultOptions = {
    doorWidth: 200,
    doorHeight: 400,
    doorDivisionWidth: 5,
    totalWidth: 735,
    totalHeight: 500,
    startOffsetTop: 50,
    startOffsetLeft: 50,
    strokeColor: "#aaa",
    fillStyle: "#ccc",
    lineWidth: 5
}
```

Fabric.js expects `strokeWidth` to be a number and you were passing it as a string. You can check the documentation: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#strokeWidth and the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2e17803/2/

Comment: In the fiddle I gave, I can see that correct door is logged on the console upon selecting. Isn't that what you needed?

Comment: @Вася Аристов if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done. Sorry, new here